# How to stop a UIView from scrolling with tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableViewController and I put a UIView right under the navigation item and above the actual table. The problem that I have is that the view scrolls with the tableview.

How would I get it to behave exactly like the nav bar, and have the items in the tableview scroll behind it.

Rather than having the view scroll, it should remain in its position and have everything go behind it. Sorry for reiterating, but I've found thats necessary sometimes.

[image]

Comment: You don't want a table view controller. Just place a tableview in a view controller and place the view in front of the tableview.

Comment: @madmik3 would that ruin everything that I have going on currently? Is there no other way?

Comment: Correct, it is a necessary change. `UITableViewController` can't have anything else besides a table view. You might be able to copy and paste some of your cell subviews into your new view controller but constraints might not copy. File a radar with apple if you don't like how things work.

Comment: Or just override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to keep the view where you want it, and skip the radar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view you're placing above the cell in the storyboard becomes the table view's `tableHeaderView`.

You can make the header view appear fixed by resetting its `frame.origin` to the table view's `bounds.origin` every time the table view lays out its subviews:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UIView *header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    CGRect frame = header.frame;
    frame.origin = self.tableView.bounds.origin;
    header.frame = frame;
}
```

Result:

[image: demo of stationary table view header]

Comment: This is easily the best, most concise answer I've seen. I had a feeling that I didn't need to implement massive change. Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the map view to move then you could set its user interaction to false.

Alternatively you could set the header of your tableView (if you only have one section) to the map view.